# Object Reference in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am relatively new to ASP.NET. I am working on a website project, and want to use the inbuilt database ASPNETDB and link in a couple custom databases. The problem is when I try to implement the CreateUserWizard tool, the user is created into the aspnet_users and other related tables, but no values are entered into the custom tables. Below is the source code I am using in the UserCreated event handler alongwith the screenshot of the wizard. Please guide me how to proceed. I only need to populate the tables.

```
public partial class Admin_TeacherRegister : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    

    }
    protected void CreateTeacherWizard_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateTeacherWizard.UserName, "Teacher");

        WizardStep createWizard = CreateTeacherWizard.FindControl("newTeacher") as WizardStep;

        MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser(CreateTeacherWizard.UserName);
        Guid newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;

        TextBox fname = createWizard.FindControl("txt_fname") as TextBox;
        TextBox lname = createWizard.FindControl("txt_lname") as TextBox;
        DropDownList dept = createWizard.FindControl("deptDropDown") as DropDownList;

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string insertSql = "INSERT INTO UserProfiles(UserId, FirstName, LastName,DeptID) VALUES(@UserId, @Fname, @Lname, @Dept)";

         using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
          myConnection.Open();
          SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", newUserId);
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", fname.Text.Trim());
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", lname.Text.Trim());
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", dept.SelectedValue);
          myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

The UserWizard is pretty simple. In addition to the default fields, it has three fields, FirstName,LastName, and a dropDownList. These fields in addition to userId, which is a shared key between aspnet_user and my custom table AdditionalDetails are required to be inserted

Comment: Do you get any particular error message when running this?

Comment: Where does "object reference" come into things? And, OBTW, your `SqlCommand` should also be in a `using` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using like the following,

1. Add the user to the system using `ASPNETDBConnectionString`
2. Then get the userid
3. Now, form the query that will insert the custom data in to your required tables, assuming that the built-in and the custom data reside in the same database.
4. If built-in and custom data reside in separate databases, you will have to hit the db twice, 1. for inserting the default user details and getting the userid & 2. to insert the additional data against the userid, but in a different db.

Comment: Solved it! I did it in a different manner. I had converted the CreateUserWizard into a custom one. So I added an event handler on the step change. When the user was initially created, I updated the secondary custom table with NULL values but stored the USERID. And later, when the event fired, I updated the values. 


I dont know what was wrong initially, but I guess the problem was that after the user was created, my query wasn't being updated with the parameters in the custom text boxes added to the user wizard.